# Chameleon ZPT templates

Tags: python, templates, pyramid, chameleon

I have created a .pt template as that contains the following snippet

```
<span class="help-block">
   ${password_confirm}
</span>
```

My Problem is that the password_confirm field will not always be rendered by pyramid framework so it displays the error below

```
chameleon.utils.NameError

NameError: password_confirm
```

I understand i am suppose to use a tal:condition but everything i am trying is failing. Can someone help me on how i am suppose to go about variables that will not always be rendered in the template.

Answer (score 6):

```
<span class="help-block" tal:condition="exists:password_confirm">
   ${password_confirm}
</span>
```

should work

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can add `tal:on-error="nothing"` in the span tag. Then, if error occurs, the whole span will not be rendered.

```
<span class="help-block" tal:on-error="nothing">
   ${password_confirm}
</span>
```

You can use something else instead of nothing.

UPDATE: this approach is not generally advisable, but can be useful as simplest in some cases.

UPDATE2: another variant (not checked with Chameleon)

```
<span class="help-block" tal:condition="password_confirm|nothing">
   ${password_confirm}
</span>
```

Comment: that works but i was looking for something along the lines of tal:omit-tag="not:bold

Comment: Not sure how omit-tag could work in this case. It just means, that <span> and </span> will be omitted, but the content will be rendered.